# BindingSource is null even when the DataSource has regular data

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingsource

I have a `DataGridView` that loads data from a file. I also want to use the DropDownFilter Column - I've used the one from [Karl Erickson on Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/aa480727(v=msdn.10)). It works all good while the columns are set in the Designer Mode.

I need to set the DGV and DropDownFilter columns programmatically since I don't always want to have all the columns with Filter. The problem is that the DGV is autogenerating its column type automatically.
The solution might be the `DGV.AutoGenerateColumns = false`, however this will throw a BindingSource error while adding new DropDownFilter column to the DGV, let me describe:

The DropDownFilter column has a property `FilteringEnabled`, where the following code returns `null` to the `BindingSource data` object, even when the `DGV.DataSource` contains relevant data:

`BindingSource data = this.DataGridView.DataSource as BindingSource;`
You can see in the image, that the DataSource is not empty, it has its columns and data as needed:
[DataSource visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahfAZ.png)

Is it possible to create the DTG with custom column type in the way I intend, or am I missing something? How can DataSource return null to BindingSource when this DataSource contains regular data?

**Update 1**

Minimal code to reproduce the err:
**Form1.cs**

```cs
// Create WinForm app, add DataGridView control and the code below

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            LoadToDtg();
        }

        private void LoadToDtg()
        {
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

            // Prepare DataTable columns fill with data
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Col1");
            dt.Columns.Add("Col2");
            dt.Columns.Add("Col3");
            dt.Columns.Add("Col4");

            dt.Rows.Add("ValueA1", "ValueA2", "ValueA3", "ValuA4");
            dt.Rows.Add("ValueB1", "ValueB2", "ValueB3", "ValueB4");
            dt.Rows.Add("ValueC1", "ValueC2", "ValueC3", "ValueC4");

            // The DataSource binding could be used here too, however it yelds the same error
            //dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                DataGridViewAutoFilterTextBoxColumn newColumn = new DataGridViewAutoFilterTextBoxColumn
                {
                    HeaderText = col.ColumnName,
                    DataPropertyName = col.ColumnName
                };

                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(newColumn);
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
```

The `DataGridViewAutoFilterTextBoxColum` refers to already [mentioned project @ Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/aa480727(v=msdn.10)). I didn't paste it here since it has 1400+ lines of code. You can download the zip directly [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23459)

Comment: _”How can DataSource return null to BindingSource when this DataSource contains regular data?_” .. ? … It can’t and you show no code that demonstrates this. Please show us a reproducible example where `data` is `null`. Currently your question shows a picture of the code and we can see a `DataTable` with some data. But that is it… we have to take your word that `data` is `null` and in my small tests, I was unable to get a `null` value as you describe. I suggest you create a [MRE] that demonstrates what you claim.

Comment: @JohnG Sorry about that, the reproducible example with instructions were added into the original post.

Comment: Well… after looking at the custom column you linked to… one thing I noted in the “Dependencies” section is that in order for it to work … _”The DataGridView.DataSource must be set to a BindingSource component.”_ … I do not see this in your code. The posted code is setting the grids `DataSource` as a `DataTable`. Have you considered making a `BindingSource` and use the `DataTable` as a `DataSource` to the `BindingSource` and then set the grids `DataSource` to the `BindingSource` as required?

Comment: After further testing, I do not get the error you described… Setting the `BindingSource`’es `DataSource` to the `DataTable dt` and then setting the “grids” `DataSource` to the `BindingSource` worked as expected as to filtering and without errors. The initial error I got was from the custom column complaining that the grid’s data source was not a binding source. Can you show an example where you get the error you described?

Comment: @JohnG I know that in the given example I didn't use `BindingSource`, however I tried to use BS in the original project, obviously incorrectly implemented. After reading your answers, I reviewed the code once again and there it was - I've assigned `BindingSource` to the `DataGridView` at the wrong time for some reason. I'm a goofus.
Thank you for your guidance, it solved my problem!